# How To Fit Full Length 16x Nvidia T-600 Into A 4x Slot?

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

I am buying a New Dell workstation 3660 . Dell will install two Nvidia T-600 graphics cards which will run 8 monitors.

I have 12 Monitors ( 1920x1200 Resolution )

Now there is only one 4X slot left where another 16X card will not fit which can run 4 leftover monitors.

Is there a way to run 3rd full length 16X graphics card Nvidia T-600 which will run 4 more monitors ?

This workstation does have latest USB 3.2 Type C ports & two Display Ports.

Can I use a 4X to 16X Riser card & place 3rd graphics card there ? Would the bandwidth be enough from 4X slot ?

Has anyone tried anything that works ?

Any other ideas ?

Thank You

Comment: I think the better question would be is there enough power connections from the power supply.  Dell isn’t known to provide a lot of extra PSU connections. I think the PCIe bandwidth will be the least of your worries. What processor does the system have.  How many PCIe lanes exist directly to the processor is hardware based. Since were talking Dell OEM hardware your likely 100% reliant on lanes directly to the processor for all PCIe functionality

Comment: Out of a choice of 300W, 500W & 750W, I have chosen 750W..

Comment: Out of a choice of 300W, 500W & 750W, I have chosen 750W.. CPU I chose Intel i-7 12700, how many PCIe lanes exists is beyond my knowledge. This is their newest Dell 3660 workstation. It has 3 graphics slots & they are giving me 2 Nvidia T-600 full lenght cards & only one slot is empty & it is 4X. How can I run 3rd Nvidia Full length card ? T-600 is an entry level or may be mid range card. System has plenty of latest USB 3.2 Type C ports & two Display ports. Can they be used for 4 monitors ?

Comment: The 12700 has 20 PCIe lanes. What is the bandwidth to each of the T-600 cards.  You should [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment.

Comment: I am sorry.  This is getting too technical for my knowledge so I don't know the bandwidth to each T-600 cards. I would be grateful if you can tell me if there is a way to run extra 4 monitors either using the leftover X4 slot or using DP ports or using USB 3.2 Type-C ports or some other way.

Comment: In order to provide an answer to your question you will have to figure out the answers that those very basic questions about your hardware.